# Subtracting only TIME (in minutes) from two DATE TIME columns in a csv file using Python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the question I have on my dataset:

Check the distribution of the number of minutes it takes between the time a '111 - Building fire' incident has been logged into the Computer Aided Dispatch system and the time at which the first unit arrives on scene. What is the third quartile of that distribution. Note: the number of minutes can be fractional (ie, do not round)

The columns include both date and time. I only want to use the time so I can subtract it from both rows and get the distribution. Here is my current code below:

```
time_of_issuance = dataset.loc[dataset['INCIDENT_TYPE_DESC'] == '111 - Building fire', 'INCIDENT_DATE_TIME']
time_of_creation = dataset.loc[dataset['INCIDENT_TYPE_DESC'] == '111 - Building fire', 'ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME']

print(time_of_issuance)
print(time_of_creation)
```

Here is the output of the snippet above:

```
91         01/01/2013 12:58:10 AM
199        01/01/2013 02:22:56 AM
440        01/01/2013 06:20:49 AM
492        01/01/2013 07:59:48 AM
569        01/01/2013 09:47:27 AM
                    ...          
1735758    11/01/2016 03:54:41 PM
1735841    11/01/2016 04:48:49 PM
1736021    11/01/2016 07:05:58 PM
1736100    11/01/2016 08:36:32 PM
1736286    11/02/2016 12:32:51 AM
Name: INCIDENT_DATE_TIME, Length: 10379, dtype: object
91         01/01/2013 01:00:50 AM
199        01/01/2013 02:25:23 AM
440        01/01/2013 06:26:13 AM
492        01/01/2013 08:03:33 AM
569        01/01/2013 09:49:25 AM
                    ...          
1735758    11/01/2016 03:56:52 PM
1735841    11/01/2016 04:54:09 PM
1736021    11/01/2016 07:10:00 PM
1736100    11/01/2016 08:38:33 PM
1736286    11/02/2016 12:37:23 AM
Name: ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME, Length: 10379, dtype: object
```

I want to subtract only the time (in minutes) between both columns as seen in the output. How can I do that using Python? I've tried using .dt.time but it throws an error for me.

Find the data head below:

```
{'IM_INCIDENT_KEY': {0: 55672688,
  1: 55672692,
  2: 55672693,
  3: 55672695,
  4: 55672697,
  5: 55672698,
  6: 55672699,
  7: 55672700,
  8: 55672703,
  9: 55672705},
 'FIRE_BOX': {0: 2147,
  1: 818,
  2: 9656,
  3: 7412,
  4: 4019,
  5: 1328,
  6: 688,
  7: 9604,
  8: 2897,
  9: 2602},
 'INCIDENT_TYPE_DESC': {0: '300 - Rescue, EMS incident, other',
  1: '735A - Unwarranted alarm/defective condition of alarm system',
  2: '300 - Rescue, EMS incident, other',
  3: '412 - Gas leak (natural gas or LPG)',
  4: '735A - Unwarranted alarm/defective condition of alarm system',
  5: '735A - Unwarranted alarm/defective condition of alarm system',
  6: '353 - Removal of victim(s) from stalled elevator',
  7: '651 - Smoke scare, odor of smoke',
  8: '331 - Lock-in (if lock out , use 511 )',
  9: '710 - Malicious, mischievous false call, other'},
 'INCIDENT_DATE_TIME': {0: '01/01/2013 12:00:20 AM',
  1: '01/01/2013 12:00:37 AM',
  2: '01/01/2013 12:01:17 AM',
  3: '01/01/2013 12:02:32 AM',
  4: '01/01/2013 12:01:49 AM',
  5: '01/01/2013 12:02:45 AM',
  6: '01/01/2013 12:03:55 AM',
  7: '01/01/2013 12:04:03 AM',
  8: '01/01/2013 12:04:37 AM',
  9: '01/01/2013 12:05:10 AM'},
 'ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME': {0: '01/01/2013 12:14:23 AM',
  1: '01/01/2013 12:09:03 AM',
  2: '01/01/2013 12:04:55 AM',
  3: '01/01/2013 12:07:48 AM',
  4: '01/01/2013 12:06:27 AM',
  5: '01/01/2013 12:07:55 AM',
  6: '01/01/2013 12:13:10 AM',
  7: '01/01/2013 12:06:19 AM',
  8: '01/01/2013 12:11:02 AM',
  9: '01/01/2013 12:08:20 AM'},
 'UNITS_ONSCENE': {0: 1.0,
  1: 3.0,
  2: 1.0,
  3: 4.0,
  4: 6.0,
  5: 3.0,
  6: 1.0,
  7: 4.0,
  8: 1.0,
  9: 6.0},
 'LAST_UNIT_CLEARED_DATE_TIME': {0: '01/01/2013 12:20:06 AM',
  1: '01/01/2013 12:30:06 AM',
  2: '01/01/2013 12:15:18 AM',
  3: '01/01/2013 12:40:11 AM',
  4: '01/01/2013 12:24:56 AM',
  5: '01/01/2013 12:18:20 AM',
  6: '01/01/2013 12:30:33 AM',
  7: '01/01/2013 12:11:21 AM',
  8: '01/01/2013 12:23:29 AM',
  9: '01/01/2013 12:10:29 AM'},
 'HIGHEST_LEVEL_DESC': {0: '1 - More than initial alarm, less than Signal 7-5',
  1: '1 - More than initial alarm, less than Signal 7-5',
  2: '1 - More than initial alarm, less than Signal 7-5',
  3: '1 - More than initial alarm, less than Signal 7-5',
  4: '1 - More than initial alarm, less than Signal 7-5',
  5: '1 - More than initial alarm, less than Signal 7-5',
  6: '1 - More than initial alarm, less than Signal 7-5',
  7: '1 - More than initial alarm, less than Signal 7-5',
  8: '1 - More than initial alarm, less than Signal 7-5',
  9: '1 - More than initial alarm, less than Signal 7-5'},
 'TOTAL_INCIDENT_DURATION': {0: 1186.0,
  1: 1769.0,
  2: 841.0,
  3: 2259.0,
  4: 1387.0,
  5: 935.0,
  6: 1598.0,
  7: 438.0,
  8: 1132.0,
  9: 319.0},
 'ACTION_TAKEN1_DESC': {0: '00 - Action taken, other',
  1: '86 - Investigate',
  2: '00 - Action taken, other',
  3: '44 - Hazardous materials leak control & containment',
  4: '86 - Investigate',
  5: '86 - Investigate',
  6: '64 - Shut down system',
  7: '86 - Investigate',
  8: '70 - Assistance, other',
  9: '00 - Action taken, other'},
 'ACTION_TAKEN2_DESC': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: '64 - Shut down system',
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'ACTION_TAKEN3_DESC': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: '82 - Notify other agencies.',
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'PROPERTY_USE_DESC': {0: 'UUU - Undetermined',
  1: 'UUU - Undetermined',
  2: 'UUU - Undetermined',
  3: '429 - Multifamily dwelling',
  4: 'UUU - Undetermined',
  5: 'UUU - Undetermined',
  6: '429 - Multifamily dwelling',
  7: '960 - Street, other',
  8: '429 - Multifamily dwelling',
  9: 'UUU - Undetermined'},
 'STREET_HIGHWAY': {0: 'E 138 ST',
  1: 'W 46 ST',
  2: '116 ST',
  3: '43 ST',
  4: 'WYCKOFF AVE',
  5: 'HAMILTON AVE',
  6: 'AVEOFAMERICAS',
  7: '102 ST',
  8: 'BOYNTON AVE',
  9: '52 ST'},
 'ZIP_CODE': {0: 10454.0,
  1: 10036.0,
  2: 11418.0,
  3: 11103.0,
  4: 11385.0,
  5: 11215.0,
  6: 10001.0,
  7: 11418.0,
  8: 10472.0,
  9: 11219.0},
 'BOROUGH_DESC': {0: '2 - Bronx',
  1: '1 - Manhattan',
  2: '5 - Queens',
  3: '5 - Queens',
  4: '5 - Queens',
  5: '4 - Brooklyn',
  6: '1 - Manhattan',
  7: '5 - Queens',
  8: '2 - Bronx',
  9: '4 - Brooklyn'},
 'FLOOR': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: '1',
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: '18',
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'CO_DETECTOR_PRESENT_DESC': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'FIRE_ORIGIN_BELOW_GRADE_FLAG': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'STORY_FIRE_ORIGIN_COUNT': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'FIRE_SPREAD_DESC': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'DETECTOR_PRESENCE_DESC': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'AES_PRESENCE_DESC': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan},
 'STANDPIPE_SYS_PRESENT_FLAG': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question because I don't think your approach is great.  Try this:

```
delay = (
    dataset
    .query("INCIDENT_TYPE_DESC == '111 - Building fire'")
    .eval("ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME - INCIDENT_DATE_TIME")
    .divide(pd.Timedelta("1m"))
)
```

`delay` will be a `pandas.Series` of minutes between the log date and the arrival time, i.e. it represents a distribution.

To find the 3rd quartile for example do this:

```
delay.quantile(0.75)
```

**edit**

You may need to make sure your datetime data is `pandas.Timestamp`.  Do this to convert, and then run the solution afterwards

```
dataset["INCIDENT_DATE_TIME"] = dataset["INCIDENT_DATE_TIME"].apply(pd.to_datetime)
dataset["ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME"] = dataset["ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME"].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

**edit 2**

For older pandas versions:

```
df = dataset.query("INCIDENT_TYPE_DESC == '111 - Building fire'")
delay = df["ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME"] - df["INCIDENT_DATE_TIME"]
delay = delay/pd.Timedelta("1m")
```

Comment: When I try the code you have provided above I get the error "Maximum recursion depth exceeded" @Riley

Comment: can you do `dataset.head(10).to_dict()` and post the results so we have some data to work with?

Comment: Please check the question, I have added a screenshot of the head

Comment: The point of posting the results of `to_dict` is so we can run `pd.DataFrame(your_dict_data)` to reconstruct your data - without typing it from scratch.  A screenshot doesn't help with this unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, you can now find it in the question itself

Comment: Can you try and run the code I've added at the end, which converts to pandas Timestamps.  The solution runs ok for me on your data once I make the conversion.

Comment: I'l run it now and update you. thanks.

Comment: I get this error now: "unknown type timedelta64[ns]"

Comment: what version of pandas are you using?  Also can you comment out the `divide` line and see if it at least runs without error on your machine?

Comment: I'm running on Google Colab pandas latest available version 1.3.5. When I comment out the divide line I get the same error.

Comment: Ive put an alternate solution in **edit 2**.  It's the same approach just written without method chaining.